# JavaScript, Promise, what's wrong with it?

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm very new to Promises. I have the following code:

```
    const cintTotalRequests = 25000;
    var blnNext = true, intRequest = 0;
    do {
        if ( blnNext != true ) {
            continue;
        }
        blnNext = false;
        info.msg("Request#" + (++intRequest));
        info.msg("Creating promise");
        var myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myError) {
            const cstrURI = "http://localhost:8000/"
                        + "?cn=Tesla&cy=2024&cm=1&cd=8&ds=clickcomp&rt=10&u=1";
            http.get(cstrURI, res => {
                let data = [];
                const headerDate = res.headers 
                                && res.headers.date 
                                ? res.headers.date : 'no response date';
                info.msg('Status Code:', res.statusCode);
                info.msg('Date in Response header:', headerDate);

                res.on("data", chunk => {
                    data.push(chunk);
                });
                res.on('end', () => {
                    info.msg('Response ended: ');
                    myResolve(data);                    
                });
            }).on("error", err => {
                var strMsg = "ERROR:" + err.message;
                info.msg(defs.RED + strMsg + defs.RESET);
                myError(strMsg);
            });
        });
        myPromise.then(function(data) {
            console.log("myPromise.resolve(" + data + ")");
        }, fnError = function(strError) {
            console.log("myPromise.reject(" + strError + ")");
        });
        break;
    } while( intRequest < cintTotalRequests );
```

As far as I can see the callback on the http.get isn't called. I've put **console.log** in the callback to see if it's executed. It isn't. Can anyone help because I know the request isn't being received by the server as thats also running on my system with debug enabled.

With the **break** in the while loop, it works for one iteration. I need to learn how to implement **await**.

Comment: @Mushroomator,as I said in my post, I am new to promises, so any help you can give is very much appreciated.  I can see that the issue is because I'm not waiting, how do I implement **await** ?

Comment: Convention is to name the `myResolve, myError` parameters `resolve, reject`.

Comment: "*I need to learn how to implement await.*" - uh, yes, just replace the `myPromise.then(…)` by `await myPromise`, and the loop will work.

Comment: @Bergi, I then see **await** expressions are only valid for **async** functions...

Comment: @SPlatten Yes, mark the function that this code is contained in as `async`

Comment: @Bergi, thank you, can you be more specific?

Comment: @SPlatten Not unless you can show the whole code - I'm assuming we see just an excerpt? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core issue - this is not how Node.js work. It has something called Eventloop and the principle is very straightforward. It has just one thread that executes your code (there is actually thread pool for I/O operations, but thats invisible for you). The Eventloop takes event on "top" which at some point is the code you post and execute ALL synchronous context it has first. Then takes another event to process.

So that `do-while` will always be first fully executed as it is synchronous part of your app (even if it runs for hour) before the callback `http.get(cstrURI, res => {` is executed.

If you need to wait for promise to be finished first, you need to return it from this part of the app and somewhere write `myPromise.then(...)` and put whatever you want in that .then part

---

To answer to your question we need more code/context of what you are doing.

Maybe this will help you understand how it works:

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  console.log('I will set new callback in next line. Then the synchronous part will continue and that will be executed later');
  setTimeout(()=> {
    console.log('Executing after timeout')
    resolve('Resolving promise');
  }, 1000);
  
  console.log('Promise is constructor - if you create it, the synchronous part is executed as well');
});

promise.then(str=>console.log(str));

console.log('The program finishes the synchronous part here and something else can be executed once availablein Event Loop');
```

The core question is - why do you even need Promises or how the rest of the app look like?

In general, if you just write

`http.get(cstrURI, res => {});` it will do the GET request, no promises needed

Comment: Thank you, how do I do that?

Comment: I am trying to write a client to my server module which will test it, the client will need to make up to 25,000 requests as if it were multiple clients.  Thats what the while loop will do.  If there is a simpler way to do it please tell me.

Comment: @SPlatten - it would be way easier to use load testing tool, this one for example is also in Javascript: https://gatling.io/open-source/

Comment: Consider a load testing tool such as artillery.

Comment: @libik, possibly, although I started out down that path by downloading a tool already written but it didn't include all the functionality I required.  So I thought it would be easier to write my own.

Comment: Ah, actually its not Javascript, but some their own scripting language, though its quite easy to make such loadtest on localhost.

Comment: I don't think the problem is actually promise related at all....I think the loop itself is preventing the http get request from working.  If I do just 1 iteration it works.  No promise used.

Comment: @SPlatten - then you can use this library: https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#parallelLimit

Comment: @libik, installed that module and modified code, can't seem to get it to do anything.